# Set static_folder path for all routes

Tags: python, flask

I have my Flask app initialized like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static/dist", template_folder="../static")
```

For the moment, I want to catch all routes and render the same template (which is a React app):

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
    def any_root_path(path):
        return render_template('index.html')
```

This works for all URLs having only one slash, as my static folder is located one step up. Example: localhost:5000/home gets the static folder at:

```
localhost:5000/static
```

However when I try to access paths with more than one slash (for example localhost:5000/home/whatever),
Flask tries to get the static folder with the path

```
localhost:5000/home/static/dist
```

What I want is to set the static_folder path as the same throughout, and not relative to the Route matched. Is this possible? Have I misunderstood something?

My file structure for reference:

```
my_app/
  server/
    app.py/    # my Flask app
  static/
    dist/
      someJavascript.js
    index.html
```

Comment: Are you using the url helper to link to static assets in your `index.html` template? `url_for('static', filename='hello.js')`

Comment: No, I will read about that, seems like it could be what I'm looking for

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot @OluwafemiSule